# select value from array at desired index using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have an array which have 5 values from index 0 to 4. i want to store the values in my 5 model properties.

```
  public IEnumerable<fields> ConvertTList(List<string[]> rows)
    {
        var tList = new List<fields>();
        foreach (var item in rows)

        {
            var ListReading = new fields

            {
           //model properties names are:

            // date, user,campaign,adgroup,changes

            };

            tList.Add(ListReading);
        }
         return (tList);
}
```

this is my code when foreach is executed item get 5 values. i want to store the values in model. how i can i store them using linq

Comment: _"how i can i store them using linq"_ In general, don't ask Linq to store something, it's purpose is to query something.

Comment: Where is the instance of the `model`? Is it `ListReading`? Are you looking for something like `ListReading.date = item[0]; ListReading.user = item[1]; // etc.`?

Comment: @rao check answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<fields> ConvertTList(List<string[]> rows)
{
    return rows.Select(x => StringsToField(x));
}

fields StringsToField(string[] source)
{
    return new fields
    {
        date = source[0],
        user = source[1],
        campaign = source[2],
        adgroup = source[3],
        changes = source[4],
    };
}
```